# Need help compiling that example from OpenCV

Tags: opencv, compilation

I need help to compile that piece of [code](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp):

It has some stuff that I need for my project, but I can't compile it.

I compile the whole ´OpenCV´ library from the source, following instructions right [there](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation):

But there's big problems:

1 - in the include files, in directory `"opencv2/stitching"`, there's not sub-directory called "detail" (there's one in the source files, but not in the compiled version in `/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching`).

2 - in the current version, in the sample, in stitching_detailed.cpp, there's no modification at all regarding this!

Also, I didn't have any error while compiling... there's only warnings for unused variables...

MORE INFO:

So, I'm using this to compile:

> g++ stitching_detail.cpp -o stitcher `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_gpu

But there's a lot of errors in opencv_stitching like:

> undefined reference to `cv::gpu::buildWarpCylindricalMaps(cv::Size_, cv::Rect_, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, float, cv::gpu::GpuMat&, cv::gpu::GpuMat&, cv::gpu::Stream&)'

Is there a way to remove the dependencies to opencv_gpu ? Because the only problems that I have right now are caused by this!

IMPORTANT:

In the configuration, it's specified that I want to compile OpenCV without CUDA, I clearly have the following third-party information:

> --   Other third-party libraries:
>
> --     Use IPP:                    NO
>
> --     Use TBB:                    NO
>
> --     Use Cuda:                   NO
>
> --     Use Eigen:                  NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you compiled the library without CUDA support and there are functions that needs it. 
The compiller is trying to link against the cv::gpu functions and they are not added at the compiled library if you don't use CUDA flag during CMAKE solution generation. 
To avoid this behaviour you have two options:

1. Recompile OpenCV with CUDA flag. **(you will need to install all CUDA
   dependencies first)**:
2. Remove all cv::gpu calls from the example code.

If you are at windows environment, you can easily download the pre-compiled library with cuda support and test the code. If you don't have CUDA support, probably the code will crash during  cv::gpu functions.

The second option is pretty easy to do. The code has declared *using namespace cv*, so you just need to look for all gpu::(function_name) calls and erase it. Just take care to not use --try_gpu argument because I didn't read all the code and this probably will call some undefined behaviors during execution time.

Comment: even if my machine doesn't support CUDA... is it possible to have the dependencies ?

Comment: apparently, you can install the toolkit even if your PC doesn't support CUDA... just hope it will recompile properly!

Comment: Well, I've never tried to compile the code without CUDA hardware, but I don't see a reason to not being able to compile it. As mentioned in my answer, even if you compile your code, probably your program will crash at any gpu functions calls. OH, and I've edited my answer. I typed it on my cellphone and wasn't able to write a more robust answer.

Comment: thanks... it's compiling now... it's not running fines because there's an illegal instruction somewhere... but at least it's compiling!

Comment: So, it doesn't run at my job, but at home, it works great... so, I need a better computer at my job! Thanks a lot for your help.